# Hide content in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to hide a content in Vue JS if the account logged in is not my account. When I open my profile page, I can see the content writer section. While if I open my friend's account then the content writer section is hidden.

Here is my code:

```
<div v-else class="q-pa-md">
        <p class="text-body1 text-bold">Content Writer</p>
        <p class="text-subtitle2 q-ma-none">Kesempatan menulis artikel</p>
        <div class="text-center q-my-sm">
          <q-btn
            label="Mulai Ajukan"
            no-caps
            unelevated
            class="text-bold"
            @click="dialog = true"
            color="primary"
            v-if="!user.is_writer"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Tried replacing the `v-else` to `v-if = "isMe"` just like what I did to the other section but it didn't work.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What do you actually have in your `user.is_writer` state?

Comment: that is used if I already registered the content creator (my status is a content creator)

Comment: Could you give more details? Can this object be undefined or alike?

Comment: So I have a news website, the user can apply as a content creator in this website. ```user.is_writer``` defines that the user is already registered as a content creator while ```isMe``` defines that the user logged into the website is my account. What I want is I can always see the content creator section at my profile page, while whenever I open another user's page, then the content creator section is hidden